# what sets make up the powerset of all natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What sets will union and make the powerset of all natural numbers?

Comment: Can you describe an element of $U$? -- And even if on replaces "countable" with "(countably) infinite", $C$ contains all supersets of the even numbres

Comment: Looks like $C$ is the whole power set of $\mathbb N$, as every subset of $\mathbb N$ is countable (assuming finite counts as countable as well). $U$ is empty. Thus, $C=\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ itself is uncountable. Altogether, very awkward example...

Comment: @StinkingBishop: You're so right! And I didn't even think about it... The same examples, as am exerise for students, would work if instead we consider finite and infinite subsets.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: What is the union of these two sets $C\cup U$? And what do we know about the cardinality of this union?

Once you answer the questions above, you can argue by contradiction. Assume both $C$ and $U$ are countable. Then their union $C\cup U$ is also countable. But …